# Recovering forgotten removed packages names

Tags: debian, apt, package-management

After a software remove on my Debian 10.3 XFCE, apt package manager advised that a lot of packages **that I really need** can be removed because they was "automatically installed":

```
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  cups-pk-helper espeak-ng-data exfalso fonts-font-awesome fonts-lato
  fonts-roboto-slab gir1.2-atspi-2.0 gir1.2-gst-plugins-base-1.0
  gir1.2-gstreamer-1.0 gir1.2-gtksource-3.0 gir1.2-javascriptcoregtk-4.0
  gir1.2-keybinder-3.0 gir1.2-notify-0.7 gir1.2-polkit-1.0 gir1.2-secret-1
  gir1.2-soup-2.4 gir1.2-webkit2-4.0 gir1.2-wnck-3.0 javascript-common
  libao-common libao4 libatk-adaptor libbrlapi0.6 libdotconf0 libespeak-ng1
  libjs-jquery libjs-modernizr libjs-sphinxdoc libjs-underscore liblouis-data
  liblouis17 libpcaudio0 libsonic0 libspeechd2 mlterm mlterm-common
  mlterm-tools ncurses-term orca psf-unifont python3-brlapi python3-certifi
  python3-cups python3-cupshelpers python3-feedparser python3-gst-1.0
  python3-idna python3-louis python3-musicbrainzngs python3-mutagen
  python3-pyatspi python3-pyinotify python3-requests python3-smbc
  python3-speechd python3-urllib3 quodlibet sound-icons speech-dispatcher
  speech-dispatcher-audio-plugins speech-dispatcher-espeak-ng
  sphinx-rtd-theme-common system-config-printer system-config-printer-common
  system-config-printer-udev ttf-unifont unifont x11-apps x11-session-utils
  xbitmaps xbrlapi xfonts-unifont xinit
Use 'sudo apt autoremove' to remove them.
```

That are really bad news because if I want to remove a package in the future with the `apt --purge autoremove` command (e.g.), my system could be breaked. So I just remember have been removed `xserver-xorg-video-nouveau` and, after reinstalling that package, the trouble persist.

The real issue was that apt have been removed more than that package, and just installing it again could be solved the dependency tree.

Solution in answers.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Following a comment from [A.B](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/251756/a-b) about /var/log/apt, I found `cat /var/log/apt/history.log`. I re-installed the forgotten packages and that was sufficient.

```
Start-Date: 2020-05-06  01:50:43
Commandline: apt remove xserver-xorg-video-nouveau
Requested-By: jeanfar (1000)
Remove: xserver-xorg-video-nouveau:amd64 (1:1.0.16-1), task-desktop:amd64 (3.53), task-xfce-desktop:amd64 (3.53), xserver-xorg-video-all:amd64 (1:7.7+19)
End-Date: 2020-05-06  01:50:53
```

I think you would like to know that using `-` or `*-` can exclude all packages you don't really want. My use case: `sudo apt install -V --show-progress task-desktop task-xfce-desktop xserver-xorg-video-all libreoffice*- firefox-esr*- speech-dispatcher*- orca*-`